# What is a combinator in Prolog?

Tags: prolog

Please give an example of a combinator in Prolog.  I am developing a State Saving Interpreter in Prolog that contains backtracking parts that includes "retry" in trace, and to get to the point, what exactly is the combinator that results in different combinations of results?

Answer (score 0):

In Prolog, combinators (clauses, not predicates) glue together combinations of results.  For example:

```
c(A,B):- a(A),b(B).
a(1).
a(2).
b(3).
b(4).

A = 1,  } here, the combinator clauses a and b give 
B = 3 ; } glued-together results
A = 1,  
B = 4 ;
A = 2,
B = 3 ;
A = 2,
B = 4.
```

Comment: Where is this terminology from?

Comment: It was from the Prolog lecturer's representation, but I have read about clauses being referred to as combinators separately.

Comment: Alternatively, "or" (written as `(<Goal 1> ; <Goal 2>)` may create goals (or sets of goals) as combinators.